# Building a 45 degree brace

Tags: building, angles

I'm trying to reproduce my own house in Lego, and attached is a photo of the porch above my front door that is supported by a 45 degree wooden brace:

[image: Photo]

At my current scale, the vertical white wood with the '71' on it is one brick wide. What technique can I use to build the 45 degree wooden brace? I guess it doesn't have to be exactly 45 degrees, but my attempts in LDD never join correctly with a horizontal piece to form the roof of the porch (although it's not obvious from this screenshot, I can't extend the horizontal plate to join the brace as the studs don't line up).

[image: LDD]

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for something that's actually load bearing?  Or just something that's aesthetically "close"?

Comment: Something aesthetically close, it doesn't need to bear any load.

Comment: Have you checked if you elevate or lower the bottom connection by one plate will that allow you to connect the horizontal plate at the top. It may adjust the angle a bit, but at some point the two should connect.

Comment: I've had a play around but it's kind of tricky in LDD, and I haven't managed to get anything to work yet. I suppose it'd be easier with real bricks but I don't have any of these kinds, and was hoping it might have been a 'solved problem' !

Comment: It's a good idea to have at least one or two of most pieces around so you can experiment with them in real life. LDD is not the best to figure out if two pieces would fit. The pieces you are using here are not expensive, so it may be worth to get some to play around with the angles.

Comment: I don't know that those bricks are the best - that's part of the point of my question, I guess. I was hoping to get pointers as to what bricks work for this kind of thing too. They may not be expensive individually but adding postage (there's no store nearby) adds up :(

Comment: Yours look like a reasonable solution. I would approach the problem the same way as you did. Perhaps also trying out hinge plates besides just hinge bricks. That way you could smooth down the top with tiles, and also you have more room for adjustments for the angles and connections.

Comment: If you are just going for something aesthetically close, and not load bearing, why do you need the hinge piece on the top?  Just push the long hinge plate up in to the "awning" and then your problems are solved.

Comment: Nick2253 has a good point.  Or you can not use plates at all, and just use a rod with one end stuck in a tile with clip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has answered this, I'll reproduce my comment as an answer:

> If you are just going for something aesthetically close, and not load bearing, why do you need the hinge piece on the top? Just push the long hinge plate up in to the "awning" and then your problems are solved.